# How to prevent a tap event delivered to superview?

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

There is a UIView named viewA, viewA has a UITapGestureRecognizer, I can't modify the recognizer's target code.
And viewA has many subviews. For some specific subviews, I want they don't deliver tap event to viewA when I touch them (for other subviews, they should deliver tap event to viewA). What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set viewA as delegate of recognizer. then use delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

check if touch is in unwanted subviews:

```
for(UIView *v in unwantedSubviewsArray){
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:v];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(v.frame, touchLocation)){
        return NO;
    }
}
return YES;
```

Comment: I can't modify recognizer's delegate. Are there any other ways?

Comment: you can try overriding hitTest:withEvent:

-(UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event                                               Do this in viewA

Answer (score 1):

Add another UITapGestureRecognizer to these subviews, so the taps won't be delivered to the superview.

Comment: There are some problems: one of the subviews is a UIToolBar, if I add a doNothing Recognizer to it, buttons on the toolbar doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array with the views you want to avoid reacting to touch:

```
NSArray <UIView *> *untouchableSubviews; //will contain the views you don't want to touch
```

and override the hitTest in your container view (viewA in your case)

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UIView *view = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if ([_untouchableViews containsObject:view]) {
        return nil; //this view will pass touch events to his superview
    }
    else{
        return view; //this view will handle touch events itself
    }
}
```